# onclick not triggered when clicked

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm facing a simple JS problem. I have wrote this code:

```js
function dash1() {
  var self = this;
  document.getElementById("vizContainer").src = "https://xxx";
}
function dash2() {
  var self = this;
  document.getElementById("vizContainer").src = "https://yyy";
}
```

```html
<div class="mf123_options d">
   <input onclick="dash1();" style="margin:0.5rem;" type="radio" id="first_dashboard" name="mf123_dashboards" value="first_dashboard" checked>
   <label for="first_dashboard">1st Dashboard</label>
</div>
<div class="mf123_options d">
   <input onclick="dash2();" style="margin:0.5rem;" type="radio" id="second_dashboard" name="mf123_dashboards" value="second_dashboard">
   <label for="second_dashboard">2nd Dashboard</label>
</div>
<iframe id="vizContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="/default.asp">
</iframe>
```

When I tried to clicked to change the iframe it doesn't work. I have tried many things without result

Comment: Please provide reproducible code. There is missing `vizContainer` in this one.

Comment: You have an extra div in your html markup. Delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Click` event only works, if you click on the radio button itself, not if you click on the accompanied label element.
Use the `change` event instead.

```js
function dash1() {
  var self = this;
  document.getElementById("vizContainer").src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300";
}
function dash2() {
  var self = this;
  document.getElementById("vizContainer").src = "https://placekitten.com/g/200/300";
}
```

```html
<div class="mf123_options d">
   <input onchange="dash1();" style="margin:0.5rem;" type="radio" id="first_dashboard" name="mf123_dashboards" value="first_dashboard" checked>
   <label for="first_dashboard">1st Dashboard</label>
</div>
<div class="mf123_options d">
   <input onchange="dash2();" style="margin:0.5rem;" type="radio" id="second_dashboard" name="mf123_dashboards" value="second_dashboard">
   <label for="second_dashboard">2nd Dashboard</label>
</div>
<iframe id="vizContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="/default.asp">
</iframe>
```

Also I recommend not to use the `on<event>` attributes in your HTML code, but instead use the `addEventListener` method

```js
function dash1() {
  document.getElementById("vizContainer").src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300";
}

function dash2() {
  document.getElementById("vizContainer").src = "https://placekitten.com/g/200/300";
}

document.getElementById('first_dashboard').addEventListener('change', dash1)
document.getElementById('second_dashboard').addEventListener('change', dash2)
```

```css
.mf123_options [type=radio] {
  margin:0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="mf123_options d">
  <input type="radio" id="first_dashboard" name="mf123_dashboards" value="first_dashboard" checked>
  <label for="first_dashboard">1st Dashboard</label>
</div>
<div class="mf123_options d">
  <input type="radio" id="second_dashboard" name="mf123_dashboards" value="second_dashboard">
  <label for="second_dashboard">2nd Dashboard</label>
</div>
<iframe id="vizContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="/default.asp">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
<input onclick="dash1();"
```

to

```
<input onclick="dash1(this);"
```

And in your function try to take a parameter called self. Maybe that might help?
Also In the html you call the function dash() when there is no function dash() on dash1() and dash2()

Comment: I tried this without result. Again I can't change iframes

Comment: well is the function itself working meaning does it run on the click?(you can test that by adding console.log("it works") before the changing of the iframe)

Comment: When I clicked on the second dashboad i see this: 

Uncaught ReferenceError: dash2 is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Comment: then maybe you are not pointing to the direction of your js file

Comment: add <script src="location of file"></script> just before the body tag

Comment: The project is on Apache with a lot of files. Now I'm working on file mf123 (.php and .js). Until now all my funcctions was pointing the same file (I mean mf23.php with mf23.js , mf24.php with mf24.js etc...)

Comment: I am realy sorry but I dont know anything on php